# Create a button which creates a widget in flutter

Tags: flutter, materialbutton

I wanna define a function or something like that to make a new widget on my button press,
Also, I wanna create that widget in a specific column.
Anybody can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can define bool variable to control show or hide that widget and in button onPressed method change that variable in setState.

something like this code:

```
var _showWidget = false;

  void changeShow(){
    setState(() {
      _showWidget = !_showWidget;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          RaisedButton(
            child: _showWidget? Text('Show'): Text('Hide'),
            onPressed: changeShow
          ),
          if (_showWidget)
            Container(
              width: 150,
              height: 50,
              color: Colors.green,
              child: Center(child: Text('Hello Word')),
            ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

well you can basically use invisible and visible field in your widget i.e. the widget is already made and u can assign a function later to it ..ex when the button is pressed the widget becomes visible and you pass a function or value to it.

Comment: It'll make a blank space, won't it?

Comment: i believe you are not using the correct syntax for what you want to achieve .if the widget is fetching data from a server u can try making a future builder for it ,